# Uncaught exception: Class 'Aws\GEmail\Exception\GEmailException' not found in phar

Tags: aws-php-sdk

I'm working on migrating (somewhat urgently) from AWS php sdk version 1.4.6.1 to version 3.178.1. In v1.x, we were using AmazonSES->send_email to send emails without attachments and AmazonSES->send_raw_email to send emails with attachments. Upon migrating we were able to get SesClient->sendEmail method to work as expected; however, sending with an attachment (SesClient->sendRawEmail) is trying to throw a "Aws\GEmail\Exception\GEmailException":

> Uncaught exception: Class 'Aws\GEmail\Exception\GEmailException' not found in phar:///path/to/aws_v3.178.1.phar/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line (195)

The content of the email is base64 encoded MIME-Version 1.0. It has plain text, html, and attachment sections. Has been tested successfully on sdk v1.x

Google searches are turning up absolutely nothing regarding "GEmail". Skimming through some of the sdk source code and searching through the docs have also provided no leads. I can supply additional information as it becomes relevant. Any ideas?

### Edit

Still no resolution on why this Exception type cannot be found. We were able to achieve the desired behavior by using the PHPMailer library (as shown in AWS PHP SDK documentation) to form the MIME message. I'm guessing the MIME message from our older code was somehow malformed. I would still be curious to know what happened.